# What proportion, roughly, of EM radiation in the average UK or US home is visible light?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light

I know the answer will vary between times of day, location, activity in the home, etc. I’m interested in very broad approximates.

For example, I’ve read that visible light makes up 0.0035% of the electromagnetic spectrum. But I’m guessing that’s referring to the range of all existing EM wavelengths that visible light comprises.

Would the percentage of EM radiation that is visible light an average home be similarly tiny? Or could it be much bigger?